# How could deploy an EAR file in Glassfish Server with Eclipse Glassfish Plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, glassfish

I want to deploy an ear project in glassfish application server using of Eclipse glassfish plugin (in servers tab), but I can't add my ear project add as a resource to this plugin. I want to know is it possible to deploy an ear project instead of war by this plugin?
I tried this issue in both of Juno and Indigo eclipses.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the Eclipse plugin from http://glassfishplugins.java.net/. You can deploy an EAR project in Eclipse by clicking "Run on Server" and selecting your glassfish instance. 
If this is not possible in your case there is probably something wrong with your setup and you'll have to give some information about the specific problem/error.